# Large file synching between Windows machines

Tags: windows, rsync

Our company has a need to daily copy large (>1GB) files over a fairly high latency WAN. 
We use DeltaCopy to achieve this, as it allows scheduling to make sure we don't choke the connection completely, however this creates a new set of problems - 
Sometimes the rsync fails because the scheduled run has been initiated before the file in question was completely generated. This requires an admin to connect to the machine manually and re-run it.

I want to implement a solution that has -

1. A queue for transfers.
2. Will not re-synch the same file, if it is already being copied.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shameless plug, my apologies, but you might be interested in [yintersync](http://www.yinter.net/). It is still in beta but works rather well. Some of the headline features include centralised management, email reporting and shadow copy support.

We actually use it to transfer 2tb of virtual machines (about 40) over a 4mbit connection.